# How to render "${" with R str_interp?

Tags: r, stringr, string-interpolation

I want to print "${var}" with `stringr::str_interp`. I can't use `stringr::str_glue`.

With `stringr::str_glue` I can do `str_glue("${{var}}")` ---> "${var}". You can find various ways to escape curly brackets with other curly brackets.

With `str_interp`, I've tried an endless number of combinations of nested and/or escaped dollar signs and brackets, but nothing works. Nothing in the docs.

**Answer:**
`str_interp("${paste0('$', '{', 'c', '}')}")`

I know that `str_interp` is being superseded by `str_glue` but I have some code I still need to work with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a variable with the notation you want of `$` and `{` like this:

```r
library(stringr)
var = '${var}'
str_interp('${var}')
#> [1] "${var}"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Yes, that does work. I'll accept this answer. It wasn't quite the right solution for this application. But I would have used that had I not figured out the `paste0` method.